# Does imshow work on OpenCV in ios?

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I am trying to produce the Simple Blob Detector in iOS using OpenCV.  I get an error related to highgui not being installed.  When I comment out the code, the offender is imshow.

```
imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints);
```

A presentation from ICVS 2013 states that highgui is not implemented in iOS so imshow will not work.  Doe anyone know whether this works yet or if there is a good workaround?

http://opencv.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/icvs/ICVS2013%20-%20Opencv%20for%20iOS.pdf

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I have been able to convert back and forth between UIImage and CV:Mat using the method available in Open CV 3.  However, I have been unable to draw the points that opencv is detecting using C++.  I am assuming I cannot do that because highgui has not been available in iOS for opencv.  Since it is not working, I am taking the centroids that were calculated using the algorithm in c++ and passing it back to iOS so that I can use the drawRect function to draw the centroids over the image.